# Ruby "no such file to load" error running spec from rake task

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, specifications

I have written tests using rspec. When I run default rake task by running

```
bundle exec rake spec
```

it gives following error, even though previously it used to work fine.

```
`require': no such file to load -- sinatra/base (LoadError)
```

but if I run tests using simple

```
ruby spec/humongous_spec.rb
```

It runs perfectly fine. I don't what is wrong with this.

Comment: what if you try run `rspec spec/`? It's for RSpec 2+

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your Rakefile

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require
```